# Matlab can't load pathdef.m

Tags: matlab, loading

When launching Matlab I get huge Error. It says it can't load pathdef.m
When I'm using Windows Explorer I'm not able to open that file either.

I'm using a school computer remotely, which is not supported by the IT department. My instructor lets me use this 'Super-Computer' for heavy calculation and he doesn't wan't to make any changes since there are other users using it simultaneously.

I've been able to just write: "restoredefaultpath;matlabrc" and I'm able to use Matlab again... but without the toolbox I think... and I believe I need it now since I'm not able to use.

```
h = figure(1);
hold on
[AX,H1,H2]= plotyy(x1,y1,x2,y2);
set(AX,{'XScale'},{'log';'log'})
set(AX,{'ycolor'},{'b';'r'})
legend('Data 1','Data 1')
xlabel('X AXIS')
ylabel(AX(1),'Y1 Axis')
ylabel(AX(2),'Y2 Axis')
grid on
```

The variable AX is defined as a number instead of a Axes Handle. Is there any way through this?

Here is the full error:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\local\pathdef.m: Cannot open file: permission denied.
Warning: MATLAB did not appear to successfully set the search path. To recover for this session of MATLAB, type "restoredefaultpath;matlabrc". To find out how to avoid this warning the next time you start MATLAB, type "docsearch problem path" after recovering for this session.
Warning: Duplicate directory name: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\local
Warning: Initializing Handle Graphics failed in matlabrc.
This indicates a potentially serious problem in your MATLAB setup, which should be resolved as soon as possible.  Error detected was:
MATLAB:undefinedVarOrClass
Undefined variable "graphics" or class "graphics.internal.initializeMATLABRoot".
Warning: Initializing Java preferences failed in matlabrc.
This indicates a potentially serious problem in your MATLAB setup, which should be resolved as soon as possible.  Error detected was:
MATLAB:UndefinedFunction
Undefined function 'usejava' for input arguments of type 'char'.
> In matlabrc at 110 
Warning: Failed to add default profiler filters.
> In matlabrc at 149 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.graphics.ModelStateFactory.createNoSelectionModelState(ModelStateFactory.java:242)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.graphics.PlotToolSetFactory$3.parseComplete(PlotToolSetFactory.java:127)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.graphics.ModelStateFactory$ProductInfoListener$1$1.run(ModelStateFactory.java:1023)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You have two different, completely unrelated questions here. The pathdef issue is an IT issue and not a MATLAB one. The second is a difference in MATLAB versions. Prior to R2014b, object handles were doubles.

Comment: @excaza , Oh, I really thought the handle problem was a consequence of the Pathdef loading error because the error says: "Warning: Initializing Handle Graphics failed in matlabrc." and "restoredefaultpath;matlabrc" is used to recover for this season. Then maybe I might be able, somehow, to use the function and set axis properties.

Comment: `set` and `get` still work with the handles being doubles, it was their behavior until R2014b.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\local\pathdef.m: Cannot open file: permission denied.`

The rest of the errors are created by it. Even the Java not initializing.

As @excaza says, it must be an IT fault. MatLab is reaching the file, but lacks permissions to open it.

Try to use your instructor account and run MatLab as admin. Some professors may have admin rights.

["On a Windows® system with User Account Control (UAC) enabled, you might be prompted to allow the update operation because it requires administrator-level permission."](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savepath.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears I have Administrator rights. I ran Matlab as and Administrator. I didn't receive same error. Just some list of other errors, f.ex. `Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: D:\Folder\Subfolder\otherusername` and now the toolbox and missing function are working correct.